# Факториал зависит от порядка условий

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия, типы-данных

Почему следующая программа компилируется

```
auto factorial(int x) {
    if (x <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    auto result = factorial(5);
}
```

, а такая же, но с переставленными условиями, - нет?

```
auto factorial(int x) {
    if (x > 1) {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto result = factorial(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если функция с дедуцируемым типом возвращаемого значения содержит несколько `return`, то те `return`, которые *позволяют* выполнить дедукцию типа, все должны дедуцировать один и тот же тип.

При этом допускаются `return`, которые *не позволяют* дедуцировать тип возвращаемого значения (напр. вызов функции, чей тип возврата еще не дедуцирован, в т.ч. рекурсивный вызов самой себя), но такой `return` не может быть самым первым в функции (при просмотре сверху-вниз).

То есть самый первый `return` в функции должен обеспечивать дедукцию типа возвращаемого значения. Остальные `return` должны либо совпадать с первым по дедуцируемому типу, либо хотя бы не мешать ему (т.е. не дедуцироваться вообще).

Answer (score 1):

Так, смотрим, говорит компилятор... а смотреть он может - вот беда! - только на шаг вперед, не возвращаясь - потому и нельзя использовать функцию, например, без предварительного объявления

```
auto factorial(int x) {
```

Ладно, запомним, что тип мы пока не знаем... И поэтому функция пока *не объявлена*.

```
    if (x > 1) {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
```

Ой! А что тут вернуть? Если тип `factorial` мы не знаем? мы сталкиваемся с использованием неизвестной, не объявленной функции :( Что еще можно сделать - только сообщить об ошибке :(

А тут -

```
auto factorial(int x) {
```

Ага, запомним, что вы не знаем возвращаемый тип, и пойдем дальше...

```
    if (x <= 1) {
        return 1;
```

Ура! теперь мы знаем, что возвращаемый тип - `int`! Функция *объявлена* полностью...

```
    } else {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
```

так что тут мы вполне можем ее использовать.